# Definition of Lebesgue integral as a supremum

Tags: real-analysis, integration, reference-request, definition, lebesgue-integral

Let $X$ be a measure space and $f\colon X\to R$ a Lebesgue-measurable non-negative function. Wikipedia claims that 
$$\int_X f=\sup_{s\le f} \int_Xs$$
with $s$ running over all step functions bounded by $f$.

Can you provide me with a citable (i.e., non-Wikipedia) reference to this definition and its equivalence to the usual definition?

Comment: What is the usual definition for you? Is it the Riemann integral?

Comment: Rudin: Real and Complex Analysis.

Comment: @ThibautDumont That wouldn't make much sense. Not every Lebesgue integrable function is Riemann integrable.

Comment: @Jakobian I know that very well, and that is why this is the right definition of the Lebesgue integral. ;)

Comment: Okay, most textbooks I‘m aware of define the Lebesgue integral via uniform limits. The function $f$ is realized as the uniform limit of step functions, and the integral is the limit of Integrals of step functions. Then it is shown that the limit of integrals does not depend on the chosen sequence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\int_X f=\sup_{s\le f} \int_Xs$ is the usual definition for the Lebesgue- integral!

Reference:

D. L. Cohen: Measure Theory, page 63.

Comment: In the Second Edition it is page 55, but thank you anyway!